# How to support actionbarsherlok for older version preior to 3.0 i.e. 2.2\2.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application in which i am using action bar sherlok library , i am doing little customization in my style for custom bar for home button , when i will run my application on post 3.0 versions it is running successfuly, but on 2.2\2.3 version it getting crashed by giving "Exception in inflate of com.actionbarshelrok.ActionbarView" error.

I am not getting how can i support older version by fixing this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post the full logcat, please.

Comment: Actually ABS supports pre 3.0 versions!

Comment: +1 this is why you want to use ABS, because it supports old versions of android. Almost every versions actully =3

 +1 you should post some traces !!